# Метод в PreparedStatement

Tags: java, база-данных, интерфейс

Просматриваю туториалы по данному интерфейсу. Все принципе понятно, кроме одного. [туториал](http://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) - здесь есть метод stmt.setInt(1,101); Причем в примерах записи и удаления первый передаваемый параметр отличается. в документации увидел это:

```
void    setInt(int parameterIndex, int x)
```

*Sets the designated parameter to the given Java int value.*

Все равно не дошло...Что реализует данный метод, и что это за значчения, которые в него передаются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у тебя есть запрос к базе следующего вида:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Status=5 WHERE ID=7
```

то ты можешь либо сам полностью составлять строку запроса и использовать обычный стейтмент:

```
String query = "UPDATE MyTable SET Status=" + newStatus + "WHERE ID=" + id;
```

А можешь использовать PreparedStatement, тогда у тебя будет:

```
String query = "UPDATE MyTable SET Status=? WHERE ID=?"
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, 5);
ps.setInt(2, 7);
...
```

Первый передаваемый параметр - индекс в запросе (грубо говоря какой ? устанавливается, счет с 1), второй параметр - значение.

Comment: а если мой запрос будет таким: "select * from table where id =?"+id

и мне нужно из таблицы в базе выбрать всю строку по первому айди записи в таблице, тогда метод setInt будет таким?:
ps.setInt(1, 1);

Comment: да, и надо убрать +id

Answer (score 3):

Ну постараюсь на пальцах объяснить, вроде бы все элементарно же
Вот пример:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into Emp values(?,?)");  
stmt.setInt(1,101);
stmt.setString(2,"Ratan");
```

Первым параметром всегда передается **порядковый номер знака ?**(начиная с 1!) prepareStatement.

То есть мы вставляем в `Emp` вот такие значения [`101`,`Ratan`] именно в таком порядке.

Если изменим код к примеру так:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into Emp values(?,?)"); 
stmt.setString(1,"Ratan");  
stmt.setInt(2,101);
```

То поменяется и порядок [`Ratan`,`101`].